# Haskell FFI double pointer argument

Tags: haskell, ffi

I would like to wrap a set of C functions with the following sig.:

```
ErrorCode Initialize(int *argc,char ***args, ...)
```

How is the double pointer represented in the FFI call? It is a pointer to a list of strings; is the following plausible?

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "lib.h Initialize"
    c_initialize :: Ptr CInt 
                 -> Ptr [String]
                 -> IO (Ptr CInt)
```

Or is the second argument a `Ptr (Ptr Char)`? I can't find this case in the literature I've read so far (Real World Haskell and the Wikibook) and my C is a bit rusty. 
Thanks in advance

-- Correction :
RWH actually shows the interface to `pcre_compile()`:

```
-- PCRE-compile.hs
foreign import ccall unsafe "pcre.h pcre_compile"
  c_pcre_compile :: CString
                 -> PCREOption
                 -> Ptr CString
                 -> Ptr CInt
                 -> Ptr Word8
                 -> IO (Ptr PCRE)
```

Which corresponds to:

```
-- pcre.h
pcre *pcre_compile(const char *pattern,
               int options,
               const char **errptr,
               int *errofset,
               const unsigned char *tableptr);
```

Comment: Maybe it's a `Ptr (Ptr (Ptr CChar))` since we have three `*` in front of `args` (and `CChar` is not `Char`).

Comment: I think the translation from C types to Haskell FFI types is pretty straightforward. `char***` is `Ptr (Ptr (Ptr CChar))`. As far as I know, there is no way to produce or consume a `Ptr [String]` (other than castPtr) because `[String]` is not `Storable`. So having your function take a `Ptr [String]` would be pretty silly - you can never actually call it from Haskell, unless you have some other FFI function specifically for creating a `Ptr [String]` for use with c_initialize.

Comment: Hint: A `char *` is usually a `CString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, taking all these suggestions into account, it seems like the most fitting signature is something like

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "lib.h Initialize"
c_initialize :: Ptr CInt 
             -> Ptr (Ptr CString)
             -> IO (Ptr CInt)
```

Thank you all! will keep you posted